# Schengen Visa single entry 180 days rule

Tags: visas, schengen, france, schengen-visas

I understand the 90/180 days rule for multiple entry.
I am from a **Non-European country**
My question is, what if I apply for a **single entry** visa to France, stay there for 10 days & then come back to my country.
Can I apply for another single entry visa within 180 days & use my remaining 80 days?
I am not sure about my second visit, but in case I have to go, what should I do then?

Comment: In fact, subsequent visits would only be limited to less than 90 days if you return less than 90 days after you leave.  If you return more than 90 days after you leave, the first day of your first visit will be more than 180 days old by the time you reach your 81st day of stay, so it will no longer count in the 90/180.calculation.

Answer (score 8):

The 90/180 rule applies to any combination of short-stay visa. (There are special cases which give more days, but that's not the problem here.) Simply count the days of presence in Schengen and if you are below 90 days within the last 180 days you are fine as far as 90/180 is concerned.

The previous visit might make it easier to get the new visa, or to get a multiple-entry visa, since you have a travel history now.